# Convert 12 hr time format to 24 hr format in perl?

Tags: perl

How do I convert "11am" and "10pm" into "11:00:00" and "22:00:00"? Is there a simple way in perl to convert this?

Comment: Yes. `Time::Piece` does time conversion. But it depends somewhat your data source.

Comment: I always find the "see strptime man page" statement in that module's document very unhelpful.  Especially as that subsequently says to see the strftime manpage, and there is no perldoc for it anywhere.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip: I believe the problem is that `Time::Piece` uses `strptime` and `strftime` from your system's run time library, which vary widely from one machine to another

Comment: @Borodin but an xs implementation seems to be included with the module, so its possible the documentation may not be correct in some cases, I think. See my comment to ikegami on Dave Cross' answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) has been a standard part of Perl since Perl 5.10 in 2007.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

for (qw[11am 10pm]) {
  my $time = Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%H%p');
  say $time->strftime('%H:%M:%S');
}
```

Comment: `hms` also works instead of the `strftime`: `say Time::Piece->strptime('10pm', '%H%p')->hms;`

Comment: True, but I've got into the habit of using `strftime()` for all formatting - it's more flexible.

Comment: Is it possible that the `%p` would fail to recognise `am|pm` for certain locales?

Comment: @Adam Millerchip, Looking at the code, it does a case-insensitive comparison against `AM` and `PM`.

Comment: @ikegami but is it not possible that `Locale` could be `#define`d differently, so that strings other than `AM` and `PM` are used?

Comment: I can't see how. But the `Time::Piece` doc says "see manpage" for `strptime` documentation. My `man strptime` says to see strftime documentation. And my `man strftime` says `%p is replaced by national representation of either "ante meridiem" (a.m.)  or "post meridiem" (p.m.)  as appropriate.`. This does not appear to be the case for the `strptime` in `Time::Piece`, hence the confusion.

Comment: @Adam Millerchip, Yes, it's possible that you could change the module to do anything else :) But as it's written, it only supports `AM` and `PM` and case variants of those.

Comment: @Adam Millerchip, Time::Piece does not use the C lib's `strptime` (since it's not always available) but its own.

Comment: That's what I thought from looking at the source. So it should really document its own behaviour, rather than instructing people to look up the man page for a different version. Anyway, bordering on off-topic now. :-)

Comment: @Adam Millerchip, If someone did want locale support, they could use DateTime::Format::Strptime. But both DateTime and Time::Piece are too heavy for this simple problem!

Answer (score 0):

Time::Piece's documentation claims that the definition of `%p` is based on your locale. So, according to the documentation, Time::Piece's `%p` can't reliably be used to handle `am` and `pm`, so you shouldn't use it.

On the other hand, Time::Piece behaves differently than documented, and `%p` will reliably handle `am` and `pm`, so it could technically be used to solve your problem despite documentation to the contrary.

I'd personally avoid that giant mess (and all of Time::Piece's other problems) and use the following lighter, simpler and clearer code:

```
my ($h, $ampm) = /^([0-9]+)(am|pm)\z/;
$h = 0 if $h == 12;
$h += 12 if $ampm eq 'pm';
my $hms = sprintf("%d:00:00", $h);   # or %02d if you want 00:00:00
```

Comment: In my experience, encouraging people to write their own date-time code leads to a mess of buggy and unmaintainable code in the future. Better to stick to a module that's widely-used and known to work correctly.

Comment: @Adam Millerchip, 1) I 100% agree. Definitely use a module for any date-time work. This question, otoh, has nothing to do with dates and time; it's just simple text manipulation. 2) Time::Piece is NOT one of the module you should be using when you do. It's a huge contributor to broken date-time code.

Comment: @Adam Millerchip, Forgot to mention that it doesn't make sense to pretend that some date 45 years ago is the same as today. Date-time problems are almost always due to assumptions of this kind, yet using Time::Piece for this problem makes exactly that kind of assumption! Don't use Time::Piece for durations, only date-times